# What should I do to avoid losing commits with Git when doing a branch merge?

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-merge

I was recently working with a team of developers using GitHub Enterprise.

I was working on a branch, let's call it `origin/feature1`, for a few hours and did several commits that I effectively pushed. At the same time, a colleague was doing a merge from `origin/master` to `origin/feature1`. When he finished the merge, it appeared that the latest few of my commits were now missing, and since I pulled before noticing the problem, I lost them locally as well.

Questions:

- Is it possible to actually lose commits which were pushed, or *everything* can be recovered (even if it means running lots of cryptic commands)?
- If yes, doesn't it mean that Git is somehow... broken? I mean, as a happy user of SVN, I never lost any work with SVN. Nor with TFS back in 2013, by the way.
- I was here when the merge was being performed. The person who did the merge didn't seem to do anything “special,” nor executing any commands which would look like they could throw away some commits. I don't suppose it was a bug (both the Git client and GitHub Enterprise are nearly up-to-date). So is there some specific argument one shouldn't specify when doing a merge? Or maybe some specific merge mode which *by default* results in the loss of commits?

Essentially, how to avoid losing half a day of work in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we both start working on `origin/feature1`, and you push some commits first, and then I try to push different commits, Git will give me an error something like

```
! [rejected]        feature1 -> origin/feature1 (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://your-repo.com'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

To properly handle this situation, I could run `git fetch origin` to get your pushed commits into my local git, and then incorporate your changes into my own with either a `merge` or a `rebase`.

What it sounds like happened in your situation (as others have articulated), is that your colleague instead ran `git push --force`, which told git to ignore the error that it gave the first time and just overwrite `origin/feature1` with my `feature1` branch.

To avoid these problems in the future, I would suggest:

- Primarily working on your own feature branches, not sharing them between developers
- Only use the `-f` or `--force` flags if you know *exactly* what you are doing.  And make sure that message is communicated to other members of your team.  It is possible to disable force pushing on branches in GitHub.

To get your changes back, you can run `git reflog`, look for the "commit" entries to find the last commit that you made on the topic, and then `checkout` the corresponding commit hash.  Your local Git keeps around every commit you make for at least 30 days, it's impossible to lose it unless you delete the `.git` directory.

Answer (score 2):

Probably your colleague pushed his branch with `-f` without having merged your changes, so, on that branch, your changes get "lost". You always get to keep your local branch so you can still do stuff with it... and if you had deleted the local branch, you can always check the reflog to get back the old commits.

How do you avoid losing time? I guess you (not YOU, but you, your team) should learn how to use the tool they have in front of them. If a developer wants to play cowboy (for the fun of it, or perhaps ignorance of the consequences of force-pushing)... well, just take it easy. For the time being, try to get your changes back.

PS Oh... and worry not. **Personal Opinion disclaimer**: After a few rounds of using git and learning about how it works, you will wonder how you made it through using SVN for so long. :-D

Answer (score 2):

The colleague was doing a merge within their local repository. `origin/feature1` refers to the a remote branch within their repository, and that's different from what you pushed. `git remote update` will do the synchronization.

I suspect that some force pushing was involved, which you generally don't want to do. If your colleague force pushed to `origin/feature1`, then it would be changing the commit to which `feature1` points away from your commits.

Your local repository probably still has the commits you made; finding them is beyond the scope of my answer.

Solution:

- Make sure force pushing is disabled on your GitHub Enterprise
- Make sure no one has any default configuration that tries to do force pushing
- Look for the orphaned commits you pushed; they should still be in your local repository.